# How do I use onblur to do multiple checks

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 functions that do entirely different things but use 1 field input to check the validations.

How could I use onblur to check both functions at the same time from the field?

```
Range of sales in the neighborhood is 
$ <input tabindex="36" type="text" id="PS_FORM/MARKET_DATA/NeighborhoodSales1" name="PS_FORM/MARKET_DATA/NeighborhoodSales1" value="{{PS_FORM/MARKET_DATA/NeighborhoodSales1}}" />
to 
$ <input tabindex="37" type="text" id="PS_FORM/MARKET_DATA/NeighborhoodSales2" name="PS_FORM/MARKET_DATA/NeighborhoodSales2" value="{{PS_FORM/MARKET_DATA/NeighborhoodSales2}}" /> 
Total # of Properties <input tabindex="38" type="text" id="PS_FORM/MARKET_DATA/NeighborhoodSalesNum" name="PS_FORM/MARKET_DATA/NeighborhoodSalesNum" value="{{PS_FORM/MARKET_DATA/NeighborhoodSalesNum}}" onblur="fill_duplicate(this, document.getElementById('PS_FORM/MARKET_DATA/Number_Comps'))" />
```

I want to check with thsi function as well

```
function get_adjusted_value( sale_price, adjustment, adjusted_value, x) {
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include your current code and the actual generated HTML so we can see how it needs to work.

Comment: right now the first line of code works perfectly--I want to add the function that is below it to the line of code above.  As you can see there is already an onblur that is validating to fill a duplicate field.  my new function will get a price from a vendor and if it doesnt match a range it will change the range to the new value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a function that calls both:

```
function MyValidation(){
    ValidateFunc1();
    ValidateFunc2();
}
```

And then attach that to the onblur:

```
<input onblur="MyValidation();" />
```

Or through late binding:

```
document.getElementById("MycontrolId").onblur = MyValidation;
```

Comment: so your saying combine my 2 functions into one function and use the single function as a call?